# How to check is the URL given is of site collection or subsite using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

how want to user ISSITECOLLECTION as flag. Means if url is site collection do this and if not do that using powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://sharepointsite/sitecollection/web/web
```

and you get an error message that says:

> Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:
>   https://sharepointsite/sitecollection/web/web

you know it's not a site collection.

In PowerShell you can handle this error with a `Try Catch` block.

Good article on error handling in PowerShell here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/05/weekend-scripter-using-try-catch-finally-blocks-for-powershell-error-handling/

An alternative could be to use the `IsRootWeb` property of the `SPWeb` object:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.isrootweb.aspx

Comment: any other way. If I get site collection in Get-SPWeb Object and then check . Is the web is site collection or not ?

Comment: Updated my answer.